# Selecting all users from unknown database table using awk

Tags: mysql, bash

I am attempting to select all users from a table where I only know that the name ends with "_users" using the command:

```
X = ($(awk -F\' '/DB/ {print $4}' wp-config.php)); mysql -u ${X[1]} -n ${X[0]} -p${X[2]} -e " select * from %_users;"
```

I am not sure what is wrong with the command and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should probably include any useful information, such as examples of the source files. This makes it easier for situations where it isn't simply a typo or misuse of a command or argument. In this case, you got lucky.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the doc about what a Good Stack Overflow question should contain [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the table names, you could query *INFORMATION_SCHEMA* to provide the table names. E.g:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE LOWER(TABLE_NAME) LIKE '%_users';
```

Then use the result set to query all the tables.

Answer (score 0):

SQL doesn't support wildcards in table names (or other identifiers). The table name must be fixed at the time you prepare the query.

You can't query from an "unknown table ending in _users." You'll have to figure out what the actual table name is.

This is no different from any other programming language. For example, you can't call a function by name if you don't know the function's name.

The "%" wildcard is for strings, when using the pattern-matching predicate `LIKE`. You can't just use it anywhere you please [when you don't know what to do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM).